# processDebugResources: Android build error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I am going to build my application with `ionic build android`, facing following problems.

> :processDebugResources
> /home/rakesh/myproject/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3:
> AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> /home/rakesh/myproject/platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4:
> AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches
> the given name
> 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

Answer (score 1):

check your compilesdkversion be equal or greater than 24